# Minimizing the word norm for the lamplighter group

Tags: group-theory, word-problem, geometric-group-theory, discrete-optimization, combinatorics-on-words

Consider the [lamplighter group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamplighter_group), which has the following group operation:

$$ (s_1, T_1) (s_2, T_2) = (s_1 + s_2, T_1 \triangle \{s_1 + t \mid t \in T_2\}) $$

where $s \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $T \subset \mathbb{Z}$. Suppose we have the following generators

\begin{align}
R &= (1, \{0\}) \\
L &= (-1, \{\})
\end{align}

I'm looking for the smallest word(s) representing an arbitrary group element $(s, T)$:

$$ \underset{w \in \{R, L\}^* : [w]=(s, T)}{\mathrm{argmin}} \lvert w \rvert $$

Let $\#R$ and $\#L$ be the number of occurrences of $R$ and $L$ in $w$. I'm trying to do this by establishing a lower bound on $\lvert w \rvert =  \#R + \#L$.  We have:

\begin{align}
\#R - \#L &= s \\
\#R &\geq \lvert T \rvert \\
\#R &\geq \max \{s\} \cup T \\
\#L &\geq -\min \{s\} \cup T \\
\#R &\geq 2 \lvert [0, s) \setminus T \rvert 
\end{align}

How can I provably minimize the [word norm](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_metric) with respect to these generators?

Comment: I think in your definition $T$ needs to be a finite subset of ${\mathbb Z}$.

Comment: That's correct.